# Loading a shapefile into PostgreSQL using shp2pgsql and outputting geographical coordinates using Django to draw a polygon in Leaflet

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I have been trying to put a shapefile into a PostgreSQL database. I then want to query the database with Django and output coordinates that I can use to draw a polygon in Leaflet.

So far I have the data in the database and the geometry field is formatted as a MultiPolygon. The shapefile has the geometries of a couple of zipcodes in Iceland. When I output the file earlier to geojson the coordinates were familiar and I could draw the polygons with leaflet.

Example coordinates `[-21.7240265318041,64.1164542988339]`

In the database after the import using shp2pgsql the geometry field looks like this 
`SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((-2418307.5715 9379398.2617,-2418549.5059 9379779.3083,-2418962.0811 9380031.9054,-2419644.0931 9380225.5631,-2420662.9013 9380629.7184,-2421471.2119 9380924.415)))`

I have tried using GeoDjango functions to convert it to the original coordinates so I can draw the polygons but without luck.

I guess there is some really simple trick that I am just not figuring out.

Here is the Django code

```
zipObject = Zip.objects.get(zip=zipCode)
zipObject.geom.coords
```

This outputs the coordinates like this.
`((((-2440522.3707000017, 9384385.061399996), (-2440762.8805, 9384356.614), (-2441141.111299999, 9384328.246699996)...`

What am I missing here?

Comment: You left out the most important part: The exact command you used to load the data. Please [Edit] your question to focus on the actual problem (any title with an "and" indicates the question is *too broad*).

Comment: These coordinates **seems** to be in 3857, and certainly not in 4326. Since you said they are stored like this in the DB, the issue occurs when importing the data

Comment: @JGH this is the thing! The Geojson that I was looking at must have been converted to 4326 and I got the information from that file. Since I am new with these coordinate systems I didn't figure out that these were the wrong coordinates in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used geodjango before, but have you tried the geojson serializer

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/

Now regarding your other issue of your coordinate are web mercator instead of WGS 84 long lat, you can fix that by doing this:

```
ALTER TABLE zip ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(MULTIPOLYGON,4326) USING ST_Multi(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom, 3857),4326));
```

WHERE **zip** and **geom** you should replace with your table name and geometry column name.